# How to get input value from dynamically created input box within a table using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to get input value from dynamically created input box within a table using ng-repeat? I have this code in my html:

```
   <table class="table table-striped" name="progressLogTable">
          <thead>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Input</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="x in progressLog track by $index ">
                <td>{{x}}</td>
                <td><input type="number" ng-model="dataInput[$index]"></input></td>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
   </table>
```

I need the value of what ever is inside of the text boxes generate when a button is clicked. Here is my JS so far:

```
 $scope.gettingInputDataFromTrackables = function(){
      $scope.dataInput =[];
  }
```

I have tried dynamically creating the model of each input by using $index but I believe I am using it incorrectly. I have also tried having my `td` generated as:

```
<td>{{x}}</td>
<td><input type="number" ng-model="progressLog[$index]"></input></td>
```

but when I do that it binds my Title header to the value of the input box at that index. To summarize I just need the value of the input box that corresponds to the Title which is also dynamically added in the `ng-repeat`.

Comment: What is inside `$scope.dataInput` when you press the submit button? How is it not working?

Comment: When I do  `console.log($scope.dataInput);` inside the submit function it logs an empty array as apposed to the values of the dynamically created input boxes.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not at all what you are asking for, but I'll let you in on the easy way in angular: Stick the model to the objects your are iterating through. For example: `ng-model="x.dataInput"`. Also `track by $index` gets so quirky once you want to add/remove any items. It will save you tons of trouble to just make sure your items in progressLog-items has a proper id field with unique values and do `ng-repeat="x in progressLog track by x.id"`. Again, not what you was asking- sorry!

Comment: I don't know why I didnt think to do that for this 'ng-repeat` I did it for every single other one in my project. Thank you for reminding me!

Comment: Solution is posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was a simple fix. Inside my function:

```
$scope.gettingInputDataFromTrackables = function(){
      $scope.dataInput =[];
      console.log($scope.dataInput);
  }
```

I was initializing `$scope.dataInput = []` every time it was clicked resulting in the data being cleared and me logging an empty array. This did not hit me for the longest time. **The fix is** :

```
     $scope.dataInput =[];
     $scope.gettingInputDataFromTrackables = function(){          
              console.log($scope.dataInput);
          }
```

Yes that's all. I just declared `$scope.dataInput` outside the scope of the function. Simple mistake and an easier fix.